# How can we plot two different dictionaries in a single x axis with one plot up and the other plot down, like a head to tail format?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, spectra

I need to plot two different dictionaries with varying keys and values (since a few keys might be present in one while missing in other) in a single plot like one on top while the other on the bottom, so that one can compare between the two.

Something like what has been given here, but I have two different dictionaries with varying keys and values count
https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/examples/pylab_examples/xcorr_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

dicts = {
    'dict_1': {'1': 10, '2': 20, 'a': 5, 'b': 10},
    'dict_2': {'1': 5, '2': 5, '3': 30, 'a': -5, 'c': -5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(dicts)
df.plot.bar(subplots=True)  # one line to perform the task
```

Result looks kinda close to the example you linked in the question. Of course you may tune it like you want.

[image]